# (HighCharts) Color reverts on mouseOut after manual mouseOver

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DUZz9/2/)

I am trying to make points of a certain group appear the same color when one in the group is mousedOver. I've successfully gotten the points to jump to the front and highlight, but for some reason, the actual point hovered over reverts to the base color after mouse out **but only on the first mouseover/mouseout**.

Whats even more confusing is that after a second mouse over, the color seems to stay. What am I doing wrong?

### JSFiddle Contents:

```
var point_color = "rgba(0,80,186,0.1)";
var hover_color = "rgba(255,166,38,1)";
var selected = {
  x : null, y : null, g : null,
  set : function(point) { 
    for (k in point) {
      this[k] = point[k];
    }
  }, 
  check : function(point) {
    return (point.g == this.g);
  }
};

var dis = { enabled: false };

function generate_data(n) {
  var out = [];
    for (var i=0; i < n; i++) {
      var g = (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'A' : 'B');
      out.push(
        {
         'x' : Math.random(), 
         'y' : Math.random(), 
         'g' : g
        }
      )
    };
  return out;
}

function highlight(point) {
  for (var i=0, l=point.series.data.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (!selected.check(this) && point.series.data[i].graphic) {
          point.series.data[i].graphic.attr('fill', point_color);
      }
  }      
  selected.set(point);
  // highlight points of same group
  for (var i=0, l=point.series.data.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (selected.check(point.series.data[i]) && point.series.data[i].graphic) {
      point.series.data[i].graphic.toFront();
      point.series.data[i].graphic.attr('fill', hover_color);
    }
  }    
}

$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      // Disable lots of junk
      chart: {type: 'scatter'}, title: {text: ''},
      legend: dis, credits: dis, tooltip : dis,
      xAxis: {labels: dis}, yAxis: {title: {text: ''}, labels: dis},
      series: [{'data' :  generate_data(100) }],
      // Hover behavior
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker : {
            lineWidth : 1,
            lineColor : "rgba(0,80,186,0.4)",
            fillColor : point_color
          },           
          states: {hover: dis}, // Disable normal hover behavior
          point: {
            events: {
              mouseOver: function () { highlight(this); }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `point.update()` instead of using fill paramet. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DUZz9/6/

Comment: I ended up using this method for the specific point being hovered over, using it for all the "group" points results in a noticeable performance hit. For those thinking of using this, make sure to disable redraw - `point.update(options, false)`

Comment: note, even with re-draw disabled, this is still much slower than altering the underlying svg through `point.graphic.attr('fill', color)`, so shouldn't be used for large number of quick changes.

Comment: Unfortunately you have only this two opitosn, incorrect fill or slower update.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure about the details of why it happens the first time, and not the second time I'm sure it relates to the `mouseOut` event for a point. Clearly something happens behind the scenes to "unmark" the point when that event fires. I wasn't able to disable `mouseOut` (no `null`, `false`...), but if that is possible I believe that to be the best trail.

I was able to avoid messing up your paintjob by making the point selected, like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUZz9/4/)):

```
events: {
    mouseOver: function () { highlight(this); this.selected = true; },
    mouseOut: function () { var point = this; setTimeout(function() { point.selected = false; }, 100); }
}
```

I'm not sure if this affects your plans in any way, but to avoid having a lot of selected points I did a timeout on `mouseOut` to de-select the point. If that doesn't matter you could ignore it.

Hopefully someone finds a more straightforward fix though, but it should give you a workaround.

Initially I though you might fix this with `plotOptions.series.stickyTracking: true` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUZz9/3/)). This works as long as you stay inside the chart area, but it then fires the `mouseOut` once you leave the chart, which ends up not actually solving the issue.